# (Django) How to make the User FK register the User name instead of a Code (int)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my `models.py`, I have the `request_author` field defined as:

```py
request_author = models.ForeignKey(
    User, 
    on_delete = models.CASCADE
)
```

This makes the `request_author` field to be registered with a user code (`int`) number in the API database. However, I would like to have it as the user name. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**`to_field=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field), for that:

> The **field on the related object that the relation is to**. By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object. If you reference a different field, that field must have `unique=True`.

So you can here set the `to_field` to `'username'`:

```
request_author = models.ForeignKey(
    User, 
    on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    to_field='username'
)
```

The `username` of the `User` model is `unique=True`, so this will not be a problem here. If you define a custom user model, than this does not *per se* holds.

Note that if you change the `to_field`, this might fail, since now it refers to a different field. In case you are just starting to build an application, it might be better to drop the database, remove old migrations, and then create a new migration file.

Comment: I don't know why but I'm receiving a `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` error after the change you suggested.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro: if the database already contains data, than evidently this goes wrong, since now this contains values, and the username does not contain these values.

Comment: But, before implementing what you suggested, I made sure to flush the database and also deleted the migration files. That should be enough of a reset, no?

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro: so you dropped the tables?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned every data and then recreated the users in order to have a clean slate. And the error appeared anyway.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro: but if you removed all migration files, Django will aim to build all tables from scratch. If the tables, with or without the data, are still present, this will evidently result in errors.

Comment: I'm new to Django (about 4 days now...), so it wasn't very clear from your last comment, but indeed you are correct. I don't know how Django deletes data exactly, I thought `python manage.py flush` would be enough, but what solved the issue was deleting `db.sqlite3` itself and then rebuilding the server with the usual migrations. Please put a note on your answer on how to properly reset the server database before altering the model and I will happily grant you the answer.